# Mysql Prepared Statement with Constraint

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a Table Structure as below

```
CREATE TABLE `eatables` (
    `Sno` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `Name` varchar(255) collate latin1_general_ci default NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`Sno`)
);
```

The Table contains Rows as below

```
insert into `eatables`(`Sno`,`Name`) values (1,'Apples');
insert into `eatables`(`Sno`,`Name`) values (2,'Oranges');
insert into `eatables`(`Sno`,`Name`) values (3,'Papaya');
insert into `eatables`(`Sno`,`Name`) values (4,'Jackfruit');
insert into `eatables`(`Sno`,`Name`) values (5,'Pineapple');
insert into `eatables`(`Sno`,`Name`) values (6,'Mango');
```

I created a Procedure to get the Count based on Name as Constraint

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS proc_fruit_count;
CREATE PROCEDURE mp_user_preference(pFruitName VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN 
     SELECT @lngCount = COUNT(Sno) 
       FROM eatables
      WHERE Name = pFruitName;

     SELECT @lngCount; 
END
```

But my Procedure is returning Null every time I execute it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your stored procedure! You also need to use IN keyword:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE mp_user_preference(IN pFruitName VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN 
     SELECT @lngCount = COUNT(Sno) 
       FROM eatables
      WHERE Name = pFruitName;

     SELECT @lngCount; 
END
```

See http://www.mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-parameters.aspx

Edit:If you want to return lngCount you can modify the stored procedure as follow:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE mp_user_preference(IN pFruitName VARCHAR(255), OUT toReturn INT)
BEGIN 
       SELECT @lngCount = COUNT(Sno) 
       FROM eatables
      WHERE Name = pFruitName
      INTO toReturn;

END
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a stored procedure here. You can solve this conveniently with a prepared statement.

```
prepare stmt from 'select count(*) from eatables where name = ?';
set @whatever = 'Mango';
execute stmt using @whatever; /* @whatever replaces the ? in the query above */
/* and if you don't need the prepared statement any more you do... */
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

Read more about prepared statements [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).